# 'Share' a VPN across internet- or VPN over VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote

First of all, apologies if this is poorly worded. Tried to explain as best as I can.

Would anyone know if it's possible to 'share' a VPN to a  remote user across the internet, on windows, *without* giving access to the original VPN credentials?

So for example;

- Person A accesses internet through VPN and can access webpage A.
- Person B *can't* access webpage A and needs to - but Person A does not want to give out credentials to the original VPN.

Is it possible for person A to say, setup a new VPN on their machine, with the VPN tunnelling traffic through, that person B can connect to - with the goal of being able to browse webpage A? (basically like a VPN proxy)

This would need to be something that they could switch on and off as needed if required?

The first thing I tried was to simply use teamviewer to remotely control the machine with VPN installed, which although not as good as a VPN, would still be acceptable. However the VPN disconnects immediately when starting.

Doesn't necessarily have to be a VPN - if there is another way it is possible, for user B to browse website A that's ok, that's the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

Both Windows and Linux allow you to setup VPN for free with (almost) built-in VPN server.

Under Windows, you'll have to create an [incoming connection](http://www.windows7library.com/blog/networking/a-quick-vpn-server-using-windows-7/) and then use internet connection sharing to share the VPN to the incomging connection.

Under Linux, you can use standard VPN servers like `pptpd` and setup NAT using `iptables`.

You can also use SSH dynamic proxying as a replacement for VPN under Linux and MacOS X.