# Possible to share a VPN connection?

Tags: vpn

I am beginning training for a new job tomorrow and I require VPN access to the company's server. However, the IT department has not sent my credentials and my trainer won't have access to them for a couple of days, thus putting me behind. So, I was wondering if it's possible for my trainer to share his VPN connection with me, over the internet (he's in Norway and I'm in the US). I assume there is some method for doing this, but I'm certainly unaware of how to go about it.

I found this question on SU (['Share' a VPN across internet- or VPN over VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/514758/share-a-vpn-across-internet-or-vpn-over-vpn)) but I'm not quite sure I understand what they answerer is saying. Could someone clear it up?

Comment: i believe you should **wait** instead of using other person's credentials which can go against company policies.

Comment: Aye. Sharing passwords is a good way to get you and your trainer fired.

Comment: Oh I certainly wouldn't want any password sharing, I was just trying to see if it's possible for him to share a VPN with me in a similar manner as sharing an internet connection. As in, I can connect to the internet via ethernet, and then share that connection to other computers in my home. I assumed there was a similar method for VPN access which wouldn't compromise any security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the possible ethical and legal elements to the question you are asking, the answer is yes.

One way would be to set up a VPN connection between yourself and the trainer in Norway, and then have the trainer in Norway NAT the VPN connection you are on onto the real VPN connection.  This is inefficient from an Internet usage point of view, but does not require the trainer give out passwords to the company VPN - so he has control by disconnecting your VPN to him, and bypasses any limitations the company might have put in place to tie down incoming VPN connections by IP address, if they have chosen to do this.

It may be possible for the trainer to give you his credentials and you set up a tunnel - but whether this works is dependent on the companies setup - particularly it won't work if its tied down by IP address, it may cause issues if both of you try and use the same VPN at the same time depending on how IP address allocation is done, and it is conceivable that the VPN is monitored and logging in from 2 locations at once could set off alarms.

Comment: I didn't think he would need to share his credentials with me, in fact I was hoping it would be just the opposite. That's what I meant by share the VPN access - his computer connects to the VPN and then my computer connects to it through his computer. He has access to the VPN and he is allowing me to use his, sort of like a "guest pass." Clearly, neither of us would want to violate any company policies.